# intellij docker integration cant open ports

Tags: docker, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

The docker integration has a weirdly proprietary config format and its very unpredictable and quite frustrating.

This is the command I want to run for my container:

```
docker run -p 9999:9999 mycontainer
```

Pretty much the simplest command. I can start my container with this command and see the ports open in kitmatic and access it from the host.

I tried to do this in the docker run config by clicking CLI and generated a json settings file (already wtf this is weird and convoluted)
[image]

It gave me this json:

```
{
  "AttachStdin" : true,
  "Tty" : true,
  "OpenStdin" : true,
  "Image" : "",
  "Volumes" : { },
  "ExposedPorts" : { },
  "HostConfig" : {
    "Binds" : [ ],
    "PortBindings" : {
      "9999/tcp" : [ {
        "HostIp" : "",
        "HostPort" : "9999"
      } ]
    }
  },
  "_comment" : ""
}
```

I then execute the run config and according to intellij the port is open (looking under the Port Bindings section of the docker tab). But its not open. its not accessible from host and kitmatic doesn't show it open either.

How do I get this working as a run config? How do I see what docker command intellij is actually running? Maybe its just using the API programatically.

Comment: See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-167575#comment=27-2196290 Since 2017.3 version Docker integration [has been reworked](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2017/11/what-does-intellij-idea-2017-3-have-in-store-for-docker-support/) with better UI and options. Please give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the intellij docker integration requires you to explicitly declare open ports with EXPOSE in the dockerfile.